# How to prevent issues with our server company

Tags: stormcrawler

We are trying to use Stormcrawler to crawl grab the index page of every site that we know a domain of - politely and ignoring any where robots.txt tell us not to. We have a database of domains - around 250m of them - and we are using that as a start. The idea is that we will crawl these once a week.

We have had a number of warnings from our server provider

Currently our crawls attempt to go to a domain name - ie abc123.com - when we do this and the domain does not resolve, this gets 'flagged'. Obviously there are MANY domains that don't resolve and point to the same IP address and therefore when we try to access a large number of domains that don't work we think this causes our provider to send an alert to us.

Our plan is after the first crawl that we will identify the domains that do not work and we will only crawl these on a monthly basis to see if they have become live, but any help would be appreciated. Apologies for being a bit naive also, so any help/guidance will be appreciated

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. Since you have to access the domains *anyway*, you have to work with the ISP...

Answer (score 1):

The alerts from your server provider are probably triggered during the DNS resolution. What DNS servers are used on your machines? They are probably the ones from your provider, have you tried using different ones e.g. OpenDNS or Google's? They might even be faster than the ones you are currently using. I'd also recommend using a DNS cache on your servers.